# Running a cron job randomly for every one hour

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I want a cronjob to run every one hour randomly. (i.e if the first job runs at 58 minutes,the second job should run at 47 minutes and the third one at 52 minutes and so on) But this should run randomly for everyone hour. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Cron itself cannot do this. You would have to resort to a workaround. You could run a script every minute and randomly decide if it should run. Keep a list of the hours it has already run in in a file per day and only run if current hour isn't already in there.

Comment: Or run a script on the hour, every hour from cron, and it then waits a random number of minutes less than 60 before doing anything. Or, run on the hour every hour from cron, but inside cron, do a random sleep of less than 60 minutes before running your script.

Comment: So `0 * * * * perl -e 'sleep int rand 3600' && yourScript` maybe.

Comment: Can i know what does perl -e does here?

Comment: `perl -e '...'` executes the code in the single quotes as a Perl program. That program sleeps for a random number of seconds less than 3,600. When that program is finished sleeping, your script will be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run a job every hour, on the hour, that sleeps up to 3,599 seconds and then executes your script:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/perl -e 'sleep int rand 3600' && /path/to/yourScript
```

Or, using `PHP` if you prefer that to `Perl`:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/php -r 'sleep(rand(0,3599));' && /path/to/yourScript
```

You can find the path to `Perl` with:

```
which perl
```

likewise for `PHP`:

```
which php
```

Comment: If your environment is at all sane, you don't need a full path to Perl unless you specifically want to use a custom-installed version.  I guess this is more common with PHP.

Comment: @triplee Agreed! I have just seen so many **cron** questions failing for the lack of a path...

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using perl or even php, just use the BASH $RANDOM built in divided by 3600 which equals one hour like so.

```
0 * * * * sleep $((RANDOM%3600)) && /path/to/yourScript
```

Keep in mind that you will probably have some race conditions with a script sleeps randomly close to an hour depending on how long it takes for your script to execute.

Comment: you would have to have `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top as usually cronjobs are run using sh and not bash